# How we can capture nanorep response?

Tags: javascript, html

I have integrated the nanorep in my html page.
I have created the account at nanorep website.

When I am asking question it is responding answer well.
I am able to plug in nanorep correctly.

Now I want a functionality that on any button click event I want the answer which is provided by nanorep.

Here is the following code I have written for this.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var _nRepData = _nRepData || []; _nRepData['kb'] = '19583554';
        function nanorep() {
            _nRepData['embed'] = { account: 'etech', container: 'Mydiv2', width: 400, maxHeight: 320, dynamicSize: true, cdcFrame: '', cdcVersion: 3, scriptVersion: '3.12.2.3' };
            (function () {
                var windowLoadFunc = function () {
                    var _nRepData = window._nRepData || [];
                    _nRepData['windowLoaded'] = true;
                    if (typeof (_nRepData['windowOnload']) === 'function') {
                        _nRepData['windowOnload']();
                        // alert(window._nRepData.toString());
                    }
                };
                if (window.attachEvent)
                    window.attachEvent('onload', windowLoadFunc);
                else if (window.addEventListener)
                    window.addEventListener('load', windowLoadFunc, false);


                var sc = document.createElement('script'); sc.type = 'text/javascript';
                sc.async = true; sc.defer = true; sc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'my.nanorep.com/widget/scripts/embed.js?account= etech';

                var _head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; _head.appendChild(sc);


                var a = document.getElementById('hdn').value = "hiddenvalue";

                
                //alert(a);
            })();
        }
       

        function answer1() {

        

            alert("answer value" + $('#hdn').val());
        }
        function btngo_onclick() {
            if (document.getElementById('hdn').value == 'hiddenvalue') {
                answer1();
            }
            else {
                alert("not working");
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
  
    <div id="Mydiv2">
    
    </div>

   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdn" />
    </form>
    <button id="btngo" onclick="return btngo_onclick()"> GO </button>
</body>
</html>
```